# Why is valgrind outputting file paths instead of a line number for the errors?

Tags: malloc, valgrind

> ==11260== Invalid write of size 4
>
> ==11260==    at 0x402872: b2_createPair (in /home/david/Documents/programming/366  terminal/mainout
>
> ==11260==    by 0x402BE9: b2_populateBigBucket (in /home/david/Documents/programming/366 terminal/mainout)
>
> ==11260==    by 0x401993: doTads_b2 (tads.c:82)
>
> ==11260==    by 0x400E82: main (main.c:159)
>
> ==11260==  Address 0x51d0318 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
>
> ==11260==    at 0x4C28F9F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
>
> ==11260==    by 0x402866: b2_createPair (in /home/david/Documents/programming/366 terminal/mainout)
>
> ==11260==    by 0x402BE9: b2_populateBigBucket (in /home/david/Documents/programming/366 terminal/mainout)
>
> ==11260==    by 0x401993: doTads_b2 (tads.c:82)
>
> ==11260==    by 0x400E82: main (main.c:159)

I'm not used to this - usually it would give me a line number for those first two lines as well.

Also - if you feel like helping me- I can't work out why it doesn't like this malloc -

```
pair2* b2_createPair(int nodeFrom, int nodeTo, int distance)
{
    pair2* p = malloc(sizeof(pair2*));
    if (p==NULL)
    {
        printf("Malloc was NULL\n"); fflush(stdout); 
    }
    else
    {
        p->distance = distance;
        p->nodeFrom = nodeFrom;
        p->nodeTo = nodeTo; 
    }

    return p ; 


}
```

(ok - just notice that p->nodeTo = nodeFrom mistake - but that doesn't affect the outcome.

the struct looks like

```
 struct pair2_t
{
    int nodeFrom;
    int nodeTo;
    int distance;
    struct pair2_t *previous;
    struct pair2_t *next;
};

typedef struct pair2_t pair2;
```

Comment: Maybe test if the result of malloc is NULL.

Comment: Consider using fprintf to print to stdout and stderr. Not answering your question, but it may make your code cleaner.

Comment: Also, you say it "doesn't like the malloc", but it's not clear what that really means. Please consider posting error messages or describing the issue in more detail.

Comment: I'm assuming that that first error message I posted refers to the malloc, or the assignments afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
pair2 *p = malloc(sizeof(pair2));
...
```

Be sure to `free()` it at some point.

Comment: Thanks. Bit of a brainfart -been at this too long. Thanks again. :)